# Mail not sending using javaMail

Tags: spring, smtp, jakarta-mail

In my application I am sending mail using spring. it works fine when I am sending mail from any gmail id, but when I am sending from another smtp server then mail is not sending.
My spring configuration for gmail:

```
<beans>
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
    <property name="port" value="587" />
    <property name="username" value="diganta.XXXXX@gmail.com" />
    <property name="password" value="******" />
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="requestToAcceptOrDeny" class="com.edfx.adb.mail.RequestToAcceptOrDeny">
    <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

But when I change the configuration into :

```
<property name="host" value="mail.mycompany.co.in" />
<property name="port" value="25" />
<property name="username" value="XXX@mycompany.co.in" />    
<property name="password" value="abc123" />
```

then no exception is generating, but mail is also not sending, password is also not checking, ie given password is right or not. I can't understand where I have done wrong.

Can anyone help me? Thanks

### Update-1

```
16:29:23,524 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Hibernate: select user0_.ID as ID7_0_, user0_.CREATE_TIMESTAMP as CREATE2_7_0_, user0_.LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP as LAST3_7_0_, user0_.VERSION as VERSION7_0_, user0_.ACTIVE as ACTIVE7_0_, user0_.DATE_OF_BIRTH as DATE6_7_0_, user0_.DATE_OF_JOINING as DATE7_7_0_, user0_.DATE_OF_RELEASE as DATE8_7_0_, user0_.FIRST_NAME as FIRST9_7_0_, user0_.FULL_NAME as FULL10_7_0_, user0_.HOME_PHONE as HOME11_7_0_, user0_.HOME_POSTAL_ADDRESS as HOME12_7_0_, user0_.LAST_NAME as LAST13_7_0_, user0_.MAIL as MAIL7_0_, user0_.MOBILE as MOBILE7_0_, user0_.ROLE as ROLE7_0_, user0_.USERNAME as USERNAME7_0_ from USER user0_ where user0_.ID=?

16:29:23,534 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4.4

16:29:23,534 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers

16:29:23,544 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers

16:29:23,544 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}

16:29:23,544 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}

16:29:23,544 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map

16:29:23,594 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Sending email ....

16:29:23,594 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]

16:29:23,604 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true

16:29:23,604 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "mail.mycompany.co.in", port 25, isSSL false

16:29:24,634 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 220 mail.mycompany.co.in ESMTP Postfix

16:29:24,644 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "mail.mycompany.co.in", port: 25
16:29:24,644 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 

16:29:24,644 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) EHLO EDFX-DESKTOP-28

16:29:24,865 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 250-mail.mycompany.co.in

16:29:24,865 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 250-PIPELINING

16:29:24,865 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 250-SIZE 10240000

16:29:24,875 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 250-VRFY

16:29:24,875 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 250-ETRN

16:29:24,875 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES

16:29:24,875 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 250-8BITMIME

16:29:24,875 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 250 DSN

16:29:24,875 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""

16:29:24,875 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "10240000"

16:29:24,875 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "VRFY", arg ""

16:29:24,875 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ETRN", arg ""

16:29:24,875 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""

16:29:24,875 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""

16:29:24,875 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""

16:29:24,895 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false

16:29:24,895 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) MAIL FROM:<Temp@EDFX-DESKTOP-28>

16:29:25,135 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 250 2.1.0 Ok

16:29:25,135 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) RCPT TO:<diganta.xxx@gmail.com>

16:29:25,365 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 250 2.1.5 Ok

16:29:25,365 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses

16:29:25,365 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG SMTP:   diganta.xxxx@gmail.com

16:29:25,365 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DATA

16:29:25,615 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>

16:29:25,615 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Date: Fri, 3 May 2013 16:29:24 +0530 (IST)

16:29:25,615 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) To: diganta.xxxx@gmail.com

16:29:25,615 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Message-ID: <628313650.2.1367578764895.JavaMail.Temp@EDFX-DESKTOP-28>

16:29:25,615 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Subject: Request to Remove Rounak Dey's Activity's Manager privilege from

16:29:25,625 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)  activity EFXL13001

16:29:25,625 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) MIME-Version: 1.0

16:29:25,625 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 

16:29:25,625 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   boundary="----=_Part_0_263230409.1367578763564"

16:29:25,625 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 

16:29:25,625 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) ------=_Part_0_263230409.1367578763564

16:29:25,625 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Content-Type: multipart/related; 

16:29:25,625 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   boundary="----=_Part_1_1514490209.1367578763584"

16:29:25,625 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 

16:29:25,625 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) ------=_Part_1_1514490209.1367578763584

16:29:25,625 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii

16:29:25,625 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

16:29:25,625 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 

16:29:25,625 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) <html><body><a href=http://localhost:8080/ActivityDatabase/req/AcceptOrDenyPermision.xhtml?activityId=EFXL13001&uniqueId=7fe18301-0bde-48da-a7d1-2bbe43b95e98&emailId=diganta.xxxx@gmail.com>Accept Or Deny request..</a></body></html>

16:29:25,625 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) ------=_Part_1_1514490209.1367578763584--

16:29:25,625 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 

16:29:25,625 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) ------=_Part_0_263230409.1367578763564--

16:29:25,625 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) .

16:29:25,855 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 164B322AB7

16:29:25,855 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) QUIT

16:29:26,046 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 221 2.0.0 Bye
```

Comment: `<prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>` try to set this in javaMailProperties and see check mail protocol log statement

Comment: @Jigar Parekh: thanks for reply. I placed the `<prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>` . ` MAIL FROM:<Temp@EDFX-DESKTOP-28>` is being displayed is it correct? here `Temp` in username of my desktop, and `EDFX-DESKTOP-28` is desktop no. not showing the mail id 'XXX@mycompany.co.in'.

Comment: can you post complete debug log

Comment: I have post the debug result. @ jiger Parekh

Comment: I have compared this posted debug report with `smtp.gmail.com`,difference is authentication is checked in case of gmail smtp,`DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2"`. but when I am using`host=mail.mycompany.co.in` then no authentication chek is performed.

Answer (score 4):

I also encountered same situation as OP. I use Spring mail to send mail and test with a gmail account work perfectly then when I apply my company mail, it didn't throw any exception but no mail received.
It took me several hours of googling, seeing debug log and trying many config but not work.
Then I write a java program using javax.mail to test and everything works. I realize the difference is in the java program I set From mail account (same as username property in spring config).
E.g. that is

> Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
>
> message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("XXX@mycompany.co.in"));

That solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks a bunch buddy! same issue here.

Comment: That was definitely the issue. Thank you dear sir.

Answer (score 0):

Your server doesn't support STARTTLS and won't let you authenticate unless you connect over SSL to begin with.  Without authenticating, it won't deliver mail outside of your domain.  Assuming you're using a new version of JavaMail, set the property "mail.smtp.ssl" to "true".

Answer (score 0):

```
    package com.karthik.spring;    

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;

    import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamSource;
    import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
    import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;
    import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessagePreparator;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile;

    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/sendEmail.do")
    public class SendEmailAttachController {
        @Autowired
        private JavaMailSender mailSender;

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String sendEmail(HttpServletRequest request,
                final @RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile attachFile) {

            // Input here
            final String emailTo = request.getParameter("mailTo");
            final String subject = request.getParameter("subject");
            final String yourmailid = request.getParameter("yourmail");
            final String message = request.getParameter("message");

            // Logging
            System.out.println("emailTo: " + emailTo);
            System.out.println("subject: " + subject);
            System.out.println("Your mail id is: "+yourmailid);
            System.out.println("message: " + message);
            System.out.println("attachFile: " + attachFile.getOriginalFilename());

            mailSender.send(new MimeMessagePreparator() {

                @Override
                public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
                    MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(
                            mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");
                    messageHelper.setTo(emailTo);
                    messageHelper.setSubject(subject);
                    messageHelper.setReplyTo(yourmailid);
                    messageHelper.setText(message);

                    // Attachment with mail
                    String attachName = attachFile.getOriginalFilename();
                    if (!attachFile.equals("")) {

                        messageHelper.addAttachment(attachName, new InputStreamSource() {

                            @Override
                            public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
                                return attachFile.getInputStream();
                            }
                        });
                    }

                }

            });

            return "Result";
        }
    }

**spring-mvc.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.karthik.spring" />

    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
        <property name="port" value="587" />
        <property name="username" value="xxxx@gmail.com" />
        <property name="password" value="xxxx" />
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <!-- max upload size in bytes -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="20971520" /> <!-- 20MB -->

        <!-- max size of file in memory (in bytes) -->
        <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="1048576" /> <!-- 1MB -->

    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
        <property name="exceptionMappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="java.lang.Exception">Error</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean> 
</beans>
```